# CSS 3d rotation doesn't work with column layout on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms, css-multicolumn-layout

I need to control the transform of some divs clicking in a html node. When these divs are with a display "inline-block" it works ok, but if I wrap them in a column layout with css3, they doesn't work (except in the first column!)

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/madelavega/hjyntsob/

In the first part, with the column layout, only the first column work: click on flip and then click on "i work", pay attention to the CSS hover style; in the 2nd and third column it doesn't work.

In the second part, with the display inline-block it works OK.

I need the column layout, but it seems to be a Chrome bug, because it works well on Firefox. Anybody know about this?

```js
$('.flip').click(function (evt) {
 $(evt.currentTarget).parents('.card').addClass('flipped');
});

$('.i-doesnt-work').click(function (evt) {
 $(evt.currentTarget).parents('.card').removeClass('flipped');
})
```

```css
/** Column*/
.content {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -moz-column-gap:      0px;
  column-count:         3;
  column-gap:           0px;
}

/* Inline-block*/
.content-di {
  display: inline-block;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
  -o-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
  transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
}

.front {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}

.back {
  webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
}

.flip {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flipped .i-doesnt-work {
  cursor: pointer;
} 

.flipped .i-doesnt-work:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Column layout</div>
<div class="content">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I doesn't work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I doesn't work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I doesn't work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div>Display: inline-block</div>
<div class="content-di">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="flip">Flip</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work too!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <span class="flip">Flip</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work too!</span>
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <span class="flip">Flip</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work too!</span>
      </div>
  </div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="front">
        <span class="flip">Flip</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <span class="i-doesnt-work">I work too!</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, we have solved this problem (which itself might be a bug in Chrome or a misunderstanding by us, since the first column has a different behaviour from the rest), by taking a different approach.

The problem happens when we try to click the "back" element inside the "card" element, when both are rotated 180 degrees around the Y axis (this means, we're trying to click the backface of the "back" element which is in fact displayed in the backface of "card" element).

The solution tries to normalize the previous situation:

- Instead of rotating the parent ("card") element, we only rotate the "front" and "back" inner divs, following a more natural behaviour.
- Initially, the front and back elements are in the same position, with the front's zIndex being greater than the back's, and the back rotated 180º around the Y axis (like having 2 pieces of paper together, one - front - facing the user, and the other - back - facing the opposite direction).
- When the user clicks the "Flip" button, we keep adding the "flipped" class to the parent ("card") element, but only the children are affected: we rotate "front" 180 degrees around the Y axis, with its backface hidden, and it will now be "facing the back of the screen"; we also clear the rotation of "back", so it will now be "facing the user", and increase its zIndex. This way we keep the flip effect and the "back" div is now on top, facing the user and receiving  events.

Here's the code (the fiddle can be found below):

```
.container {
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap:   10px;
  -moz-column-count:    4;
  -moz-column-gap:      10px;
  column-count:         4;
  column-gap:           10px;
}

.card, .front, .back {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.card .front,
.card .back {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card .front {
  background: #f00;
}

.card .back {
  background: #0f0;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/** Flipped **/
.card.flipped .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card.flipped .back {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

[The fiddle in action](https://jsfiddle.net/jfconde/m4jwaa0x/2/)